# Using remote server IP like a proxy command line on my local machine

Tags: linux, remote, proxy

I have a remote linux server with an ip like x.x.x.x.
I want to use my server to use my commands.

for example I want to use `apt-get update` command from my local machine and command run in my local machine but used my remote IP like a proxy...

How can I do that

Answer (score 0):

Do you want commands entered on your local machine to be executed on both the local machine and one-or-more remote machines?  Or do you just want to be able to run commands on the remote machine?

The latter case is easy, use ssh to login to the remote machine and start executing commands in the shell.  Anything you can do locally on the shell you can do remotely, permissions and hardware capability permitting.

With the former, you probably want something like [Cluster SSH](https://github.com/duncs/clusterssh/wiki) or [pdsh](https://computing.llnl.gov/linux/pdsh.html) to be able to run commands simultaneously on multiple machines.  Both are designed for High Performance Computing (HPC) clusters but can be used on any group of machines.

My recommendation is to use `pdsh`, it's simple to set up and works well.  I've used it on HPC clusters and on both small and large networks of servers and workstations.

Comment: No just run on my local machine... not on remote server .

Comment: In that  case, i have absolutely no idea what your question means, it makes no sense to me at all.  Please try to be a lot clearer in your question.

Comment: are you perhaps talking about running a web proxy like squid on your remote server, and configuring apt on your local machine to use it for downloading .deb packages?